# How to make an image crop and re-center as browser width changes

Tags: html, css, image

I have a custom widget area with the Visual Editor plugin setup so I can do promotions or whatever in the header area.

I have CSS classes for this widget. They control the background img, etc.

My boss told me he wanted the images responsive, but as it turned out what he actually meant is he would like them to crop and re-center as the width of the browser changes. Like in this video [home page slider cropping/re-centering](https://www.screencast.com/t/tJJ0FAmFn70a), that's taken from the home page.

My header area widget can be seen here - [100daysofrealfood.com/carrot-almond-recipe](https://www.100daysofrealfood.com/carrot-top-almond-pesto-sustainable-almond-recipes/)

As you shrink down the browser, you see the image re-sizes itself appropriately. However, my boss would like it to stay relatively largish so you can still read the text (hence the cropping) but re-center as well.

I inspected the home page and I can see it's a media query that's controlling this, so I tried to use those same things in the .responsive-image I setup in my CSS -

```
.responsive-image {
  width: auto;
  max-width: none;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition:all .2s ease;
}
```

This is the code I have in the tester widget I'm doing that's hidden on a private page -

```
<a href="https://www.100daysofrealfood.com/spring-reset-real-food-mini-pledge-
program/?utm_source=headerwidget"><div class="responsive-image"><div 
class="days100-background-header-widget days100-background-header-widget-
image-background"></div></div></a>
```

And it's just displaying the image totally uncropped. I can't share a link to this because I don't have enough reputation points.

So my question is - how do I accomplish within the div of the widget what's happening on the front page. Is this possible? I tried to do a div-class with the img settings used in the slider and that didn't work either. All of the CSS for this is going in the additional CSS area of the home page so I can't do anything that will impact that. I hope this makes sense! I really appreciate any help/tips/etc. Also please let me know if I need to show any other code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that you're looking for is background-image.

What you need to do is to use the image as a background inside a container. Then adjust your element via css.

It would look something like :

```
div.image-background{
   position: relative;
   background: url('') top center no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   width: 100%;
   height: 200px;
}
```

You adjust the rest as it suits your work.

References:

[How TO - Full Page Image](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_full_page.asp)

[Perfect Full Page Background Image](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Comment: @AmandaRosen glad that did the trick. I added some references, they are really good references to gain more knowledge about CSS.

Comment: thank you! I will check those out. I'm trying to learn as much as I can, so I appreciate those references!

Answer (score 0):

Using percentage on height/width alone would force the other to stay at proportion and would make it resposive to the browser's width.

example:

```
.responsive-image {
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition:all .2s ease;
}
```

I hope I got your question correclty but if I did this should do.